# EclipseLink 2.5.2 JPA 2.1 not fetch anything by join fetch with ManyToOne Foreign Key

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, eclipselink, weblogic12c, named-query

I had a Java EE project developed by NetBeans 8.0.1 by using EclipseLink 2.5.2 JPA 2.1 runs in WebLogic 12c.

There are two entities have many to one relationship, i.e. one FirmEntity with multiple SiteEntity. Entity relationship as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "site", catalog = "ozssc", schema = "public")
......
@NamedQuery(name = "SiteEntity.findBySiteOwner", query = "SELECT s FROM SiteEntity s left join fetch s.siteOwner where s.siteOwner.firmAbn = :siteOwnerAbn"),
......
public class SiteEntity implements Serializable {
    ......
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_owner", referencedColumnName = "firm_abn", nullable = false)
    @**ManyToOne**(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private FirmEntity siteOwner;
    ......
    get......
    set......
    ......
    @Override
    public String **toString**() {
        return "com.longz.ozssc.model.SiteEntity[ siteId=" + siteId + " ]";
    }
}
```

FirmEntity defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "firm", catalog = "ozssc", schema = "public")
......
public class FirmEntity implements Serializable {
......
@**OneToMany**(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "siteOwner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<SiteEntity> siteEntityList;
......
}
```

I defined a Remote interface to serve my business requirement as:

```
    List<SiteEntity> findSitesByOwner(String siteOwnerAbn);
```

Implement it in EJB as:

```
@Override
public List<SiteEntity> findSitesByOwner(String siteOwnerAbn) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SiteEntity.findBySiteOwner");
    /*String firmAbn = siteOwner.getFirmAbn();*/
    System.out.println("Site Owner for query by Firm ABN string: |"+siteOwnerAbn+'|');
    query.setParameter("siteOwnerAbn", siteOwnerAbn);

    return new LinkedList<SiteEntity>(query.getResultList());
}
```

This function is taken a string as parameter and return a List of SiteEntity. But very funny, EJB container print out is totally different, it print out as:

```
<Feb 27, 2015 10:37:51 AM EST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <Site Owner for query by Firm ABN string: |com.longz.ozssc.model.FirmEntity[ firmAbn=61315477824 ]|>
```

**Please note**: The content between two delimiter '|' proposed will print out a string as "**61315477824**", this is what I sent it to EJB interface from my Spring MVC controller. But EJB container print out as "**com.longz.ozssc.model.FirmEntity[ firmAbn=61315477824 ]**" and this string is the function SiteEntity.toString()'s print out.

So I never get the site list properly by this query. Is this a bug from EclipseLink or Netbeans? Why I give it a String, but they take it as Entity Object? Or something wrong in my methods?

Any advice is welcome, with plenty of Appreciation.

**Edit:**

This is how I called EJB from my MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/indexSiteEntityBySiteOwner")
public ModelAndView listSiteEntitysBySiteOwner(@RequestParam FirmEntity siteOwner) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    List<SiteEntity> siteentitys = siteEntityFacadeRemote.findSitesByOwner(siteOwner.getFirmAbn());
    System.out.println("fetched site entity list by site owner: |"+siteentitys.size()+'|');
    mav.addObject("siteentitys", siteentitys);
    mav.setViewName("siteentity/listSiteEntitys.jsp");

    return mav;
}
```

controller method take FirmEntity as parameter, return a MAV. Function findSitesByOwner was defined in EJB interface take a String as parameter and return a SiteEntity list.

Please note, I used siteOwner.getFirmAbn() get the firm's ABN, it will return a String type ABN.

Comment: Why would this be an EclipseLink or Netbeans bug?  The print out you are showing is the string parameter you pass in, the siteOwnerAbn string.  You haven't shown how you are calling the findSitesByOwner method, so my guess is you are passing it a FirmEntity instance as if it were a string rather then passing in the instance's firmAbn value.  The query correctly returns nothing, as I doubt you have a FirmEntity with a firmAbn value of "com.longz.ozssc.model.FirmEntity[ firmAbn=61315477824 ]"

Comment: Hi. Chris. Please find my updated editing, I put MVC controller here to make sure there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried printing off siteOwner.getFirmAbn() before passing it to the findSitesByOwner method?  The logs seems to show it is "com.longz.ozssc.model.FirmEntity[ firmAbn=61315477824 ]" within the method, so you need to determine how it gets this value.  Check that you haven't inadvertently changed the value in your FirmEntity instance somewhere and not persisted the change.

Comment: Thank you! Chris. I had found the problem, it was caused by Spring frame work. It alway binds my foreign key to a serialised object. I have to retrieve my foreign key from form object attribute and send it to my EJB server and then everything works well from then.